# Xcode: Do something on specific date

Tags: objective-c, xcode, date, nsdate

Hi i am trying to do something on a specific date, at the moment im just logging some random stuff, but the log appears directly when the app is launched, and not on the date that i have set. Here is my code.

```
-(void)theMagicDate{

    NSCalendar *nextCal = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *nextComp = [nextCal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [nextComp setYear:2013];
    [nextComp setMonth:3];
    [nextComp setDay:26];
    [nextComp setHour:10];
    [nextComp setMinute:05];

    UIDatePicker *nextDay = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [nextDay setDate:[nextCal dateFromComponents:nextComp]];

    if(nextDay.date){
        NSLog(@"Doing the stuff on the date");
    }
}
```

and i call this function from viewDidLoad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are making some wrong assumptions:

First `if(nextDay.date){` will always be true. Since it will only check if there is any thing assigned to the property date. Since you assigned a date to that property it will be true.

Second, the [`UIDatePicker`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) is a User Interface (UI) component that will allow the user to select a date. 
If you want to check wether the date you created with the components has pasted, is now or is in the future you will have to a method on [`NSDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Like so:

```
-(void)theMagicDate{

NSCalendar *nextCal = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *nextComp = [nextCal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[nextComp setYear:2013];
[nextComp setMonth:3];
[nextComp setDay:26];
[nextComp setHour:10];
[nextComp setMinute:05];

NSDate *dateToCheck = [nextCal dateFromComponents:nextComp];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];


switch ([now compare:dateToCheck]) {
    case NSOrderedAscending:
        NSLog(@"Date in the future");
        break;

    case NSOrderedDescending:
        NSLog(@"Date in the past");
        break;

    case NSOrderedSame:
        NSLog(@"Date is now");
        break;
}


}
```

Comment: Im trying this method, but i only get the string @"Date in the future" to work even though im trying to set the current date and time to 1 min in the future, but it doesn't know when that date has been passed.

Comment: If you set the date to one minute in the future just before you check the date that it is still in the future. If I run the above example, it will give a console log saying: `Date in the past`

Comment: Okay, so i got it to work, but only when restarting the phone. What im going for is that this view should be active and running and still initiate stuff that is going to happen on a specific date and time.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(nextDay.date){
    NSLog(@"Doing the stuff on the date");
}
```

Is always true.

You need to compare the current date with the date you selected from picker or anywhere. You need to save the future date in userdefaults or plist etc. Read it in theMagicDate method and compare the two dates, then move into `NSLog(@"Doing the stuff on the date");`

```
-(void)theMagicDate{

    NSCalendar *nextCal = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *nextComp = [nextCal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [nextComp setYear:2013];
    [nextComp setMonth:3];
    [nextComp setDay:26];
    [nextComp setHour:10];
    [nextComp setMinute:05];

    UIDatePicker *nextDay = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [nextDay setDate:[nextCal dateFromComponents:nextComp]];


     //read from plist etc
     NSDate *readDate=...


    if( [readDate compare:nextDay.date]==NSOrderedSame){
        NSLog(@"Doing the stuff on the date");
    }
}
```